# Xamarin iOS Custom Folder Access

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I have a project using Xamarin iOS in c#. I have created a 'Content' folder with the following structure:

```
   -Content
        -Images
            -1.png
            -2.png

        -Files
        -Other
```

This means I have a 'Content' folder with Images/Files/Other sub directories and then two png files in the 'Images' folder.

My problem is that when I try Directory.exists(dir*) it is only able to show directories which has files inside it. So the Images folder can be found but not the 'Files' folder.

dir* = full path to Images folder.

If I put files in the 'Files' folder then that is visible also.

I noticed that files have to be marked as Build Action -> BundleResources, however this option doesn't exist for folders.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating some empty file "dummy.txt" inside your folder and set it to BundleResources.
Then the folder should be recognized as 'not empty' and be copied to the device.